# Adding to an array list within a class in Java? Beginner

Tags: java, arrays, list, class

Still learning the basics however I've been stuck on this. I'm trying to add members to a club from the methods I've wrote, but I'm getting an error on the join method..

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Club
{
    private ArrayList<String> memberList;

    public Club()
    {
        memberList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void join(String newMember)
    {
        memberList.add(newMember);
    }
}

public class TestClub
{
    public TestClub()
    {

    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Club myClub = new Club();
        System.out.println("The club has " +
                    myClub.numberOfMembers() +
                    " members.");

        myClub.join("Gary", 5, 2019));
    }
}
```

I know I'm missing something, just can't figure out what. I create the `club` object but it won't let me add to the list. How do I get the object to accept 3 values/arguments?

Comment: `join(String newMember)` has one parameter, the `String`.  You try to pass it 3 `join("Gary", 5, 2019));`, you have to pass the correct parameters AKA `join("Gary")`.

Comment: Thanks @Nexevis ! To pass 3 seperate parameters how is that done in the join method?

Comment: You would need to create a new class, maybe Member, and put a member's info there. Then you'd need to define an ArrayList<Member> rather than of String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
myClub.join("Gary", 5, 2019));
```

You have two closing parentheses. You might want to delete the last one. Also, you have 3 variables, the string, the integer and another integer.

Maybe you want to say:

```
myClub.join("Gary");
```

or

```
myClub.join("Gary, 5, 2019");
```

Also, you haven't yet implemented the method, numberOfMembers in the Club class, so that will always fail.

```
myClub.numberOfMembers()
```

You would need to have a method in Club class that returns the number of members, meaning the memberList size.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I did have the numberOfMembers seperate so that is fine. However I edited the join method and get an error on the add.. 

 public void join(String firstName, int age, int DOB)
    {
     memberList.add(firstName, age, DOB); 
    }

Answer (score -1):

1)You have added extra closing ')' also method 'join(String newMember)' has one parameter, the String. You are trying to pass it 3 value :- join("Gary", 5, 2019);

2) Also your arrayList is of type String you can only add String values eg : "Gary" and not Integer eg : 5 or 2019.
You can also redefine method 'joins' like below for adding multiple value in single method call

```
  public void join(String ...newMember)
    {
        Collections.addAll(memberList, newMember);
    }
```

and change method call as below

```
myClub.join("Gary", "5", "2019");
```